# Поиск в строке с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Задача - получить две строки:

1. Invalid pseudocolumn \"$country_id\".
2. Message String: Unknown hostmachine name.

Из исходного текста:

> execute failed: Server message number=126 severity=15 state=1 line=1
>   server=MSSQL\MSSQL2 text=Invalid pseudocolumn \"$country_id\". Here
>   may be some text. Message String: Unknown host machine name.

Я делаю так:

```
text=(.+?\.)|String:\s(.+?\.)
```

Но он работает только по частям, вместе с оператором | (или) возвращает только первую часть. Направьте меня на путь истинный!

Comment: вы бы код и язык привели, вы может все получаете, а смотрите только на первую часть

Comment: Собираю вот здесь, в песочнице: https://regex101.com/r/sE6eP2/1

Comment: в ключи добавьте параметр `g` - он как раз и делает поиск не только первого совпадения, но и всех остальных совпадений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используется оператор `|` (*или*), то для *PCRE* нужно будет добавить знак глобального поиска, т.е. запретить поиску останавливаться после первого совпадения. Это делается с помощью `g`:

```
/text=(.+?\.)|(Message String:\s.+?\.)/g
```

А можно просто пропустить лишние символы между группами, указав их в условии поиска:

```
text=(.+?\.).*(Message String:\s.+?\.)
```

Answer (score 1):

В качестве признака, по которому идет разделение, можно использовать точки, например:

```
    (text=[^.]+\.).*\s(Message String:\s+[^\.]+\.)
```